# Ubuntu 20.04 - Reading serial port in C fails - Multiple libraries tested

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, serial-port

I've got a GPS receiver on /dev/ttyUSB2, that operates using modem AT commands. I am using libserialport to work with the serial ports (but I have also tried c-periphery, and atinout and all fail to function in the same way).

This code also works perfectly on Raspbian, so I'm completely stumped.

The function below sends an AT command to the GPS modem and expects a response. When monitoring /dev/ttyUSB2 with minicom and running my program, I can see it correctly sends the AT command (I can also verify the output buffer contains the correct number of bytes using sp_output_waiting() following the sp_blocking_write() call. Minicom also displays the expected response correctly. Great.

The problem is that my program never sees the response. sp_input_waiting() always returns 0 bytes waiting on the input buffer. sp_blocking_read() always returns 0 bytes read.

Does anybody have any idea what the problem could be?

```
VLGPSSTATUS vlDAQGPS::ATCommand(const char* at_command, const char* expected_answer, long int timeout_ms){

char answer[100], command[100];
struct timespec previous;
VLGPSSTATUS result = VLGPS_FAIL;
unsigned int bytes;

memset(answer, '\0', 100);    // Initialize the string
memset(command, '\0', 100);    // Initialize the string

snprintf(command, 100, "%s\r\n", at_command);
sp_flush(cmdPort, SP_BUF_BOTH); //Flush both serial buffers.

sp_blocking_write(cmdPort, command, strlen(command), 50);    // Send the AT command

StartTimer(&previous);
sp_drain(cmdPort); //Waits for tx_buffer to be transmitted.
Sleep(10);

//this loop waits for the answer
do {
    bytes = sp_input_waiting(cmdPort);

    if (bytes > 0)
    {
        //if there are data in the UART input buffer, reads it and checks for the answer
        sp_blocking_read(cmdPort, answer, bytes, 50);

        if(strstr(answer, expected_answer) != NULL)
            result = VLGPS_SUCCESS;
    }
} while ((result != VLGPS_SUCCESS) && ((GetTimer(previous) / 1000) < timeout_ms));

Sleep(10);
return result;}
```

Here is a minimal reproducible sample, but you would need your own serial hardware or emulation to test it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libserialport.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
char tx_buf[100], rx_buf[100];
struct sp_port *port;
unsigned int bytes = 0;

memset(tx_buf, '\0', 100);
memset(rx_buf, '\0', 100);

sp_get_port_by_name("/dev/ttyUSB2", &port);

sp_open(port, SP_MODE_READ_WRITE);

sp_set_baudrate(port, 115200);
sp_set_bits(port, 8);
sp_set_parity(port, SP_PARITY_NONE);
sp_set_stopbits(port, 1);
sp_set_flowcontrol(port, SP_FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS);

sp_flush(port, SP_BUF_BOTH);
sprintf(tx_buf, "AT\r\n");
sp_blocking_write(port, tx_buf, strlen(tx_buf), 50);
printf("TX bytes: %d\n", sp_output_waiting(port));

sp_drain(port); //Wait for outgoing transmission to finish

bytes = sp_input_waiting(port);
printf("RX bytes: %d\n", bytes);
sp_blocking_read(port,rx_buf, 10, 50); //10 should be 'bytes' but I'm forcing it here

if(strstr(rx_buf, "OK") != NULL) printf("SUCCESS\n");
else printf("FAILURE\n");

sp_close(port);
sp_free_port(port);

return 0;}
```

I've done a bit of stracing.  Mincom seems to use this sequence of polling and ioctls:

```
write(1, "Port /dev/ttyUSB2, 10:46:32\r\n", 29) = 29
write(1, "\nPress CTRL-A Z for help on spec"..., 43) = 43
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/root/.dialdir", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_DTR|TIOCM_RTS|TIOCM_CTS]) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
select(4, [0 3], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(3, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_DTR|TIOCM_RTS|TIOCM_CTS]) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
select(4, [0 3], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(3, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_DTR|TIOCM_RTS|TIOCM_CTS]) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
select(4, [0 3], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 1 (in [0], left {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=26865})
ioctl(0, KDGETLED, 0x7ffe3f10c1f0)      = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
read(0, "a", 32)                        = 1
write(3, "a", 1)                        = 1
ioctl(3, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_DTR|TIOCM_RTS|TIOCM_CTS]) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
select(4, [0 3], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 1 (in [0], left {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=934453})
read(0, "t", 32)                        = 1
write(3, "t", 1)                        = 1
ioctl(3, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_DTR|TIOCM_RTS|TIOCM_CTS]) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
select(4, [0 3], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 1 (in [0], left {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=793428})
read(0, "\r", 32)                       = 1
write(3, "\r", 1)                       = 1
ioctl(3, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_DTR|TIOCM_RTS|TIOCM_CTS]) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
```

My test program straces the following:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/ttyUSB2", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
flock(3, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB)               = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCEXCL)                      = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_DTR|TIOCM_RTS|TIOCM_CTS]) = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCMBIS, [TIOCM_RTS])         = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCMBIS, [TIOCM_DTR])         = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_DTR|TIOCM_RTS|TIOCM_CTS]) = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCMBIS, [TIOCM_RTS])         = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCMBIS, [TIOCM_DTR])         = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B115200 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_DTR|TIOCM_RTS|TIOCM_CTS]) = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCMBIS, [TIOCM_RTS])         = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCMBIS, [TIOCM_DTR])         = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_DTR|TIOCM_RTS|TIOCM_CTS]) = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCMBIS, [TIOCM_RTS])         = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCMBIS, [TIOCM_DTR])         = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_DTR|TIOCM_RTS|TIOCM_CTS]) = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCMBIS, [TIOCM_RTS])         = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCMBIS, [TIOCM_DTR])         = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCMGET, [TIOCM_DTR|TIOCM_RTS|TIOCM_CTS]) = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCMBIS, [TIOCM_DTR])         = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B9600 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCFLSH, TCIOFLUSH)             = 0
select(4, NULL, [3], NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=50000}) = 1 (out [3], left {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=49992})
write(3, "AT\r\n", 4)                   = 4
ioctl(3, TIOCOUTQ, [4])                 = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0), ...}) = 0
write(1, "TX bytes: 4\n", 12)           = 12
ioctl(3, TCSBRK, 1)                     = 0
ioctl(3, FIONREAD, [0])                 = 0
write(1, "RX bytes: 0\n", 12)           = 12
select(4, [3], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=50000}) = 1 (in [3], left {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=49984})
read(3, "", 10)                         = 0
select(4, [3], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=49367}) = 0 (Timeout)
write(1, "FAILURE\n", 8)                = 8
write(1, " - 0\n", 5)                   = 5
close(3)                                = 0
```

Comment: I suggest to [edit] your question and create a [mre], i.e. a *minimal* program we can compile and run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you run your program and "Minicom" using the `strace` tool? Using this tool, you can see which data is actually read and written and which IOCTL codes are executed. Then you can compare the difference between your program and "Minicom".

Comment: Dark Sorrow: I did a full reset, fresh install of Ubuntu, running solo or not, makes no difference.

Comment: Try sending `/r/n` before sending AT commands. Your USB to Serial convertor might be sending some garbage characters to module and it might be busy in the reading phase.
Can you print the size and contents of rx_buf.

Comment: Dark Sorrow - The program already flushes both input and output buffers before writing or reading using ioctl(3, TCFLSH, TCIOFLUSH).

Comment: Martin - I did some stracing. I've added above. 

Some additional notes:  When sp_output_waiting() is called, it executes ioctl(3, TIOCOUTQ, count). This works reliably, and returns the output buffer size. strace actually breaks this, I assume because observing the value clears the buffer. However, when sp_input_waiting() is called, it uses ioctl(3, FIONREAD, count) and it fails 99/100 times. The rx_buf however, is not empty. It contains the response.  This makes it more impractical to read the buffer because I don't know the size of the contents before attempting to read it.

Comment: Tried changing FIONREAD to TIOCINQ, but it makes no difference.

Comment: If you add another call to `sp_output_waiting()` after the `sleep(1)`, does the value change to 0 or is it stuck at 4 (e.g. due to hardware CTS not asserted)?

Comment: Ian - The value changes to 0. I think there's some kind of race condition going on. If I add any sleep() delays at all, the rx_buf always returns empty. If I remove sleep() completely, it contains the response, but FIONREAD still fails despite being executed before the sp_blocking_read().

Comment: *"The program already flushes both input and output buffers before writing or reading"* -- This is simply unnecessary and wrong.  Flushing is only required for initialization or error recovery.   You cannot reliably synchronize your program with the device driver; that is one of the reasons why data buffers are used.

Comment: *"Here is a minimal reproducible sample..."* -- This works for me ***if*** I increase the read timeout.  The output from the modified example is 3 lines: `TX bytes: 4` `RX bytes: 0` `SUCCESS`

Comment: Hi sawdust.  'SUCCESS' means the buffer was not empty, but in that case RX bytes should be > 0. The flushing is an initialization as both buffers should be clear before I send an AT command anyways.

Comment: *"... but in that case RX bytes should be > 0"* -- No, you don't understand your own code, and apparently you also don't grasp what I wrote.  The number of *"RX bytes"* in your code is sampled *too early*, i.e. before any data is available.  But when I increase the read timeout, then there is time to wait for a response to be fetched from the system buffer.  The least you could do would be to try a similar test: increase the read timeout from just 50 ms to a full second.

Comment: I did. On Raspbian, a 10 ms delay did exactly as you say, and the code works just fine. On Ubuntu, the only time I even get anything in the output buffer is if I remove all delays. It's completely counter intuitive. Also, I the requirements of the application mean the process needs to be completed within 100 ms. I don't have a second to wait.